# non-blocking write in c

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

I have read some materials about socket programming online. By default, `write()` is blocking. In some materials, `write()` only blocks when socket buffer is full. Some other materials say `write()` is blocked until all the data in the user buffer has been moved to the system buffer, which means `write()` will also block if there is not enough space for the data to place. I am wondering which statement is correct if `write()` is set to blocking.

Comment: Which socket is it? Windows?

Comment: @o_weisman Thanks for your reply. Linux system.

Comment: I suggest you add the os in question as a tag.

Comment: The Linux man pages suggest that this will write the amount of data that can be written to the buffer and will return after the data is written even if only part of the data could fit into the socket buffer, but I believe that it depends on the actual implementation of the particular system / socket.

Comment: `write()` is standardized by POSIX; it is not part of the C standard.  In any case, whether `write()` operates in blocking or non-blocking mode is a function of the file to which the write is directed. `write()`'s behavior is conditioned on the nature and properties of that file; it is incorrect to characterize any of its conditional behaviors as a "default".

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or do you have an actual programming problem to solve?

Comment: @John Bollinger This is just an theoretical question.

Comment: The two behaviors of a blocking `write` that you describe sound identical to me.  Can you elaborate on what the difference would be?  Is there any experiment you could run that would demonstrate the difference?

Answer (score 2):

> In some materials, write() only blocks when socket buffer is full. Some other materials say write() is blocked until all the data in the user buffer has been moved to the system buffer, which means write() will also block if there is not enough space for the data to place.

It is not clear to me that these are actually saying anything different.

First, what one refers to as the "system buffer" is what the other refers to as the "socket buffer", but they are the same thing.

Secondly, when the first statement says "write() only blocks when socket buffer is full" this should be interpreted as "write() only blocks when the write operation would overflow the (system) buffer". This is the same as "write() is blocked until all the data in the user buffer has been moved to the system buffer"; it is just that one says that the condition will cause write() to block and the other says that the block will cease once the condition becomes false. This is not contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

The write function behaves like the send() function when the descriptor is a socket. The write() fucntion will block if the internal buffers are full and until all the data can be sent. This assumes that the socket is blocking. Keep in mind that the write function can be interrupted by a signal; errno will be set to EINTR (the return value will be the number of bytes written when the signal was caught) and you can call write() again until all your data is sent.

See

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html

Comment: On the link to the send() function I posted above, it says that If space is not available at the sending socket to hold the message to be transmitted, and the socket file descriptor does not have O_NONBLOCK set, send() shall block until space is available. So perhaps this is the answer you were looking for. As for "until all the data can be sent" I wrote, I meant to say until all the data passed to the write() fucntion is written to the internal buffer. I apologise for the lax language and did not mean to mislead you.